# Cannot use layout_centerInParent in fragment with FracmentTransaction.replace

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an activity with a view in which I want to show a fragment. The code for the activity is like follow:

```
public class ProductListingActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_listing);

    Fragment currentFragment = new ProductListFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(enterAnim, exitAnim);
    transaction.replace(R.id.rootView, currentFragment);
    transaction.show(currentFragment);
    transaction.commit();
    getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
}
```

An here is the code of activity_product_listing.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

The ProductListFragment is just a normal fragment with the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/outerWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include
        id="@+id/headerView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/subview_home_top_title_with_back_button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/loadingImg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/home_logo_smaller_height"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My intention is to display the fragment at the place of the rootView RelativeLayout of the activity, but the problem is that the ImageView of the fragment (with the id `loadingImg`) is not display at the center of the activity although I have set `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`, but it is displayed right below the included view (the one with id `headerView`).

I can't find anything wrong with my code, may be I misunderstand something about `FragmentTransaction.replace()`. I'm using Android.app.Fragment, not the fragment in the compatibility library (if it matters). Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem. It's because when added to the view, although declared match_parent, the root view of the fragment is not set to match_parent. I set the layout params of the root view of the fragment to match_parent like follow then it worked:

```
// Expand our root view to fill parent view
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
mView.findViewById(R.id.outerWrapper).setLayoutParams(params);
```